# How can I install version of screen with vertical split in Arch linux?

Tags: archlinux, screen

Version of screen in raspbian has this functionality. I thought that Arch being rolling release it would have all the latest software, so why doesn't it have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical split in Screen isn't a part of its default functionality.  It's a user patch that several distros keep in their repository to go with Screen.  Since Arch usually keeps a more update, but 'pure' repository of software, you're missing the patch.

I don't think arch keeps the patch in their repositories, but from some Googling, you can download it [here](http://vsp4sdl.yuggoth.org/wrp_vertical_split_0.3_4.0.2.diff.bz2).

In my opinion, screen pails in comparison to Tmux.  It has a lot of the features you want built in and is far easier to use.  It might be worth a try ;)

**Edit:**  To install the patch, install it like you would a standard Linux application form source.

1. Run "./configure"
2. Run "make"
3. Run "sudo make install"
4. Delete the folder you extracted the patch to and its archive as they're no longer needed.

**Edit2:**
According to goldilocks (see comments), this will patch the applications binaries, and is *not* a plugin for an existing installation of screen.  This option will require downloading the source for screen and compiling the two together.  If you need help with that, please create a second question.

Comment: Those instructions for installing the patch(es) are *TOTALLY AND COMPLETELY* **WRONG**.  There is no configure script or makefile in that tarball.  It's a set of patches, which are `.diff` files.  You need the screen source in order to use them, you then put those files in the build directory and use the `patch` command (see `man patch`) with `-p1`.  You cannot patch an existing executable, so you should probably uninstall that.

Comment: Here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96197/how-do-i-apply-software-patches/96198#96198 IMO tmux is a good choice tho.

Answer (score 1):

There's an AUR package that includes these source patches: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=58966

If you don't know how to use AUR, then [check out the instructions here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) (it's totally worth it!).

To automate the process of installing AUR packages you could use a tool like Yaourt.

Comment: <10 rep, can only post 2 links... Source link for [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt)